# Adding custom styles to icons inside Title bar of MetroWindow

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro

I am using [MahApps.Metro](https://mahapps.com/) in my `WPF` app. The default behavior of the title bar of its [MetroWindow](https://mahapps.com/docs/controls/metrowindow) is that any icon inside it has low opacity (dimmed) display unless you mouseover the icon. Even if you don't mouseover the icon, I would like to look it the same as when you mouseover it. How can we achieve this?

**With mouseover on CupCakes icon** [I would like it to look the same even without mouseover]:

[image]

**Without mouseover**:

[image]

**MetroWindow.xaml**:

```
<mah:MetroWindow x:Class="WPF_Mah_Metro_Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mah="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
        xmlns:iconPacks="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/iconpacks"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF_Mah_Metro_Test"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        GlowBrush="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.Accent}"
        ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        Height="450" Width="800">

    <mah:MetroWindow.LeftWindowCommands>
        <mah:WindowCommands>
            <Button x:Name="btnTest" Click="btnTest_Click"  ToolTip="Open up the GitHub site">
                <iconPacks:PackIconModern Width="22" Height="22" Kind="SocialGithubOctocat" />
            </Button>
        </mah:WindowCommands>
    </mah:MetroWindow.LeftWindowCommands>

    <mah:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>
        <mah:WindowCommands>
            <Button x:Name="btnTest1" Click="btnTest1_Click"  Content="Deploy CupCakes">
                <Button.ContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <iconPacks:PackIconModern Width="22" Height="22" VerticalAlignment="Center" Kind="FoodCupcake" />
                            <TextBlock Margin="4 0 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Button.ContentTemplate>
            </Button>
        </mah:WindowCommands>
    </mah:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>
    <Grid>
    </Grid>

</mah:MetroWindow>
```

Comment: Did you try editing the Button's Style?

Comment: Take a look the similar [solution](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/issues/2290#issuecomment-168673660)

Comment: @DarkSideMoon I tried your suggested link. It works great for `Min/Max/close` buttons. But I could not find similar  Light/Dark styles properties in [WindowCommands](https://mahapps.com/api/MahApps.Metro.Controls/WindowCommands/) class. And hence, after I modified the style - from your provided link - to `WindowCommands` it did not work. I may be missing something.

Comment: @nam, I have a little bit investigation, I found [WindowButtonCommands](https://mahapps.com/api/MahApps.Metro.Controls/WindowButtonCommands/) has a lot of properties and you can do some custom things, but for [WindowCommands](https://mahapps.com/api/MahApps.Metro.Controls/WindowCommands/) there is only few properties - `DarkTemplate, LightTemplate, Theme` for customizations. Well, you can try with this properties.

Comment: @DarkSideMoon I had tried these properties to no avail. But I do appreciate you trying to help.

Comment: @nam, no problem :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To override the styles of the inner controls of the `WindowCommands` you must create your own style for it:

```
<Style x:Key="Styles.WindowCommands.Custom"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource MahApps.Styles.WindowCommands}"
       TargetType="{x:Type mah:WindowCommands}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource MahApps.Styles.Button.WindowCommands}" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
            </Style>
            <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource MahApps.Styles.ToggleButton.WindowCommands}" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
            <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource MahApps.Styles.SplitButton.WindowCommands}" TargetType="{x:Type mah:SplitButton}">
                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
            </Style>
            <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource MahApps.Styles.DropDownButton.WindowCommands}" TargetType="{x:Type mah:DropDownButton}">
                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

Now if you put this key to your `App.xaml you can use it in your App like:

```
<mah:MetroWindow.LeftWindowCommands>
    <mah:WindowCommands Style="{StaticResource Styles.WindowCommands.Custom}">
    </mah:WindowCommands>
</mah:MetroWindow.LeftWindowCommands>

<mah:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>
    <mah:WindowCommands Style="{StaticResource Styles.WindowCommands.Custom}">
    </mah:WindowCommands>
</mah:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>
```

Another solution could be to make a style for the Button directly.

*Note*: Namespace for `mah` is `xmlns:mah="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"`

Comment: Your solution worked like a charm (thank you). Using your `style` makes the icons inside the title bar look as beautiful now without mouseover as with mouseover.