# MahApps Button Icon with svg image

Tags: wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro, pathgeometry, wpf-core

I am using [MahApps.Metro](https://mahapps.com/) in my WPF app. In the title bar of my [MetroWindow](https://mahapps.com/docs/controls/metrowindow) I'm displaying an `svg` image icon as follows. In the [Path Markup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/path-markup-syntax?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) for the `svg data` when I use the `Fill` attribute value to black (`Fill="Black"`), the icon looks good (as shown in figure 1 below). But since I want to keep the default background (that is blue) of the title bar, the icon with black fill is (as expected) not very eye catching. But if use `Fill="White"`, the letters `T` and `X` of the icon are a bit dim (less bright) - as shown in figure 2 below. **Question**: Is there any way we can make the text `TeX` of the svg image (of figure 2 below) brighter, any suggestions/solutions?

**Remark**: Clicking on the following images may give you a better view (and hence better understanding of the question).

**When** `<Path Fill="Black" Data="{StaticResource buttonSvg}"/>`:

[image]

**When** `<Path Fill="White" Data="{StaticResource buttonSvg}"/>`:

[image]

**MainWindow.xaml**:

```
<mah:MetroWindow x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:mah="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
        xmlns:converters="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/shared"
        mc:Ignorable="d" Height="450" Width="800">
    <mah:MetroWindow.Resources>
        <Geometry x:Key="buttonSvg">
            M507.712 311.74c-7.903 0-13.493-0.757-16.772-2.27s-6.599-4.456-9.962-8.827l-62.298-89.284 39.85-57.757c3.363-4.54 7.945-8.66 13.746-12.358s15.343-5.549 28.627-5.549v-8.828h-68.855v8.828c5.549 0 9.878 1.387 12.989 4.161s4.666 5.843 4.666 9.206c0 1.177-0.084 2.312-0.252 3.405s-0.841 2.228-2.018 3.405l-33.293 48.93-37.832-55.74-1.135-1.387c0 0-0.378-0.967-1.135-2.9 0-2.354 1.598-4.456 4.792-6.305s7.567-2.774 13.115-2.774v-8.828h-80.205v8.828h4.54c7.735 0 13.536 0.673 17.403 2.018s6.894 3.699 9.080 7.062l53.47 79.952-46.66 69.108c-2.186 3.363-6.18 7.188-11.981 11.476s-15.932 6.432-30.392 6.432v8.827h16.413c-3.319 17.739-7.947 31.114-13.892 40.103-6.894 10.425-22.531 15.637-46.913 15.637h-37.833c-6.726 0-10.635-0.757-11.728-2.27s-1.639-4.456-1.639-8.827v-75.917h24.465c13.284 0 21.774 2.522 25.474 7.567s5.549 13.704 5.549 25.978h6.81v-75.665h-6.81c0 12.274-1.555 20.892-4.666 25.852s-11.896 7.44-26.357 7.44h-24.465v-69.108c0-4.372 0.547-7.315 1.639-8.827s5.002-2.27 11.728-2.27h35.563c22.195 0 36.445 4.287 42.75 12.863s10.635 22.868 12.989 42.877h6.558l-8.827-64.567h-129.294l-4.381-62.298h-175.795l-4.54 64.567h6.558c2.354-23.372 6.222-38.505 11.602-45.399s18.664-10.341 39.85-10.341h15.386c3.363 0 5.338 1.009 5.927 3.026s0.883 4.708 0.883 8.071v149.313c0 4.372-1.219 7.692-3.657 9.962s-10.888 3.405-25.348 3.405h-13.367v8.827h106.94v-8.827h-9.080c-14.46 0-22.868-1.135-25.221-3.405s-3.531-5.591-3.531-9.962v-149.313c0-3.363 0.168-5.759 0.504-7.188s1.597-2.732 3.784-3.91h15.638c21.186 0 34.469 3.447 39.85 10.341 5.202 6.666 8.907 21.058 11.123 43.129h-21.968v8.827h6.558c11.266 0 17.823 0.841 19.673 2.522s2.774 5.297 2.774 10.845v149.313c0 5.549-0.925 9.164-2.774 10.846s-8.407 2.522-19.673 2.522h-6.558v8.827h164.697l9.763-64.567h48.247v-8.827c-6.726 0-11.392-1.682-13.998-5.045s-3.909-6.137-3.909-8.323c0-1.177 0.084-2.312 0.252-3.405s0.841-2.228 2.017-3.405l40.103-60.028 44.39 69.107c0 1.009 0.378 1.598 1.135 1.765l1.135 0.252c0 2.354-1.555 4.456-4.666 6.305s-7.44 2.774-12.989 2.774v8.827h79.952v-8.827h-4.288z
        </Geometry>
        <Style x:Key="Styles.WindowCommands.Custom" BasedOn="{StaticResource MahApps.Styles.WindowCommands}" TargetType="{x:Type mah:WindowCommands}">
            <Style.Resources>
                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource MahApps.Styles.Button.WindowCommands}" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
                    </Style>
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
    </mah:MetroWindow.Resources>
    <mah:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>
        <mah:WindowCommands Style="{StaticResource Styles.WindowCommands.Custom}">
            <Button ToolTip="TeX icon test">
                <Viewbox Width="22" Height="22" Stretch="Fill">
                    <Path Fill="White" Data="{StaticResource buttonSvg}"/>
                </Viewbox>
            </Button>
        </mah:WindowCommands>
    </mah:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>
    <Grid>
        
    </Grid>
</mah:MetroWindow>
```

**UPDATE**:

The app does not have any issue with other icons on the other buttons and they work great with the style (shown above) provided by the user `@punker76` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65577595/1232087). The dimness of the image seems more related to its svg data. I am thinking may be there is a workaround to make it look brighter. Or, may be someone with better knowledge of svg can either find a better svg or modify this existing one.

Comment: You keep using the word svg. I do not think it means what you think it means.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I cant be sure as its a vector image but I have a feeling its to do with the rendering mode try setting bitmap scaling option to nearest neighbor or High Quality

```
RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"
```

Comment: Your suggestion did not make any difference. I also tried the similar suggestion from [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/758461/Improve-WPF-performance-with-RenderOptions-2) article but to no avail.

Comment: I've been trying to get some results but no luck, I'm not sure if this would look better but you can set the stroke thickness and colour which may improve the quality, I think its too small to fit all the pixels into one space as it looks fine when you increase the size. Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="0.5"

Comment: Your suggestion of `Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="0.5"` worked (thank you). And, it worked event better after I created another `svg` with smaller size. You can include this suggestion in your response, and I'll mark it as an `answer`.